# Number of six-digit numbers with strictly ascending digits.

Tags: combinatorics

How many strictly ascending 6-digit sequences are there, as $024579$ or $135789$, but not $011234$?

I have tried $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5 =151200$, but this is wrong.

Comment: Hint:  every sequence of distinct numbers can be listed in increasing order in exactly one way.

Comment: what is that  way

Comment: You start with the least of them, then the second least, up to the greatest.

Comment: start with 2-digit numbers to see the pattern

Comment: To be clear... you used two different words here.  Are you looking for six-digit **numbers** where 024579 is considered a five digit number rather than a six digit number due to the leading zero?  Or are you looking for six-digit **sequences** where leading zeroes are allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another hint: such a number is determined entirely by which numbers are present and which ones are absent. So in order to determine one of these numbers, then, out of the $10$ digits that exist, you simply need to choose $6$ to be present (and the remaining $4$ will be absent).

Now can you come up with a guess for how many six-digit numbers with strictly ascending digits there are? Your first guess is likely to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

choose any of the 6 digits out of these 10 in
$$C_6^{10}$$ways
now you have selected and only have one way to arrange them.
so it is the answer
$$C_6^{10}=210$$

Comment: A more common notation is $\binom{10}{6}$.